# neo4j QueryResult won't exit

Tags: java, api, neo4j

Currently I have this class.  When I remove QueryResult it runs the main method and completes on its own.  When I add QueryResult I need to manually kill the run.  How can I cause this to gracefully end?  Thanks.

```
public class TestConnect {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("starting test");
     final RestAPI api = new RestAPIFacade("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
    System.out.println("API created");
    final RestCypherQueryEngine engine = new RestCypherQueryEngine(api);
    System.out.println("engine created");
    QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query("start n=node({id}) return n;", map("id",0));
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I am using Java 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with neo4j, but QueryResults generally need to be closed, in order for java to release/clean up the connection and similar things.

Incidentally, I don't know which version of java you're using, but if it's java 7 or higher and this result implements java.lang.AutoClosable (which it probably does) you can use automated resource management! Yay!

So either manually calling: `result.close` (preferably in a finally block) or using ARM:

```
try (QueryResult> result = engine.query("start n=node({id}) return n;", map("id",0))) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

should probably do it.

Comment: so this would work, however this requires the object to implement java.lang.autocloseable

Comment: Indeed, which is a parent of java.io.Closable, so all those work as well.